# comparing perl array with Either Array

Tags: arrays, perl

I am having a scenario where i will have to compare one array with more than one array and if the array matches any of the listed ones the return value should be true . Can anyone suggest the best way please .Thanks in advance .

Comment: What do you mean by "compare arrays"? Is `is_deeply` form [Test::More](http://p3rl.org/Test::More) too much?

Comment: Sorry , i will be more clear . I have an xml coming as input for one of the screens . I am converting the xml to logical paths using XML Lib API and storing as a baseline . Now when i run my Automation tests i will get the dynamic xml again and convert as xpaths again      as i base lined it and compare both to determine if they are same.      In the process , i can have 3 different states of screen , so i need to confirm if the array matches any one of the arrays which are already saved. I will have to compare line by line because if i have some content which is dynamic ,i will replace it

Answer (score 0):

You may use [Array::Compare](https://metacpan.org/pod/Array%3a%3aCompare)

```
my @arr1 = 0 .. 10;
my @arr2 = 0 .. 10;

my $comp = Array::Compare->new;

if ($comp->compare(\@arr1, \@arr2)) {
  print "Arrays are the same\n";
} else {
  print "Arrays are different\n";
}
```

Comment: In this process , if i have some dynamic content (like logged in user) which will change per login, i am replacing the strings in each line of array , so i may not be able to compare the full array like suggested ..Kind of you for sharing your thoughts . Thankyou..